# I want to resize and img when clicked in php/html/css/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am familiar with CSS and HTML but not great with Javascript. On my website, I would like to make an image increase in size slowly when pressed and move into the center of the screen slowly. I would like this to be all just 1 long smooth animation. If it is possible to do this with just CSS that would be great however I am willing to use javascript also.

Comment: This can all be done with CSS animations. Could you show us some CSS.

Comment: This is the website. I know its not great. https://shillax.win/    I would like to make the logo in the top left hand corner large and move to the center when pressed.

Answer (score 0):

First, it's always super helpful to include code for what you've already tried. :)

To get this done you can use css transform. You don't even need an animation.

You can transform the image from:

`transform: translate(0,0) scale(1);`

to

`transform: translate(calc(100vw/2 - 50%), calc(100vh/2 - 50%)) scale(5);`

Adjust the scale or speed as needed.

[A working example](https://codepen.io/718studio/full/NzOKYq/)

Comment: Sorry about not including code. I'm new to this but next time I will. Is there a way that the movement of the object will get triggered when I press it rather than when my mouse hovers over it?

Comment: You're going to have to use a bit of Javascript. You can use an `onclick` event to toggle a class. I would check out https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp